# How can I include a jQuery plugin on my magento website?

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-plugins, flexslider

I am trying to use [this jQuery plugin](http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-image-cache-plugin-cache-images-in-browsers-local-storage) to preload my image in a flex slider on the homepage of my Magento site, but I can't figure out how to include it. How can I do this?

Comment: There is a magento exchange http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DamienBlack its a plugin ! not available there. it should be included in website separately

Comment: I'm saying you will probably get more answers there. Everyone at magento.stackexchange.com knows magento really well. No one is going to be able to answer you here. Re-ask your question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin panel CMS - Pages - Home Page - Design, add this code:

```
    <reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>../skin/frontend/<pkgname>/<themename>/js/jquery-1.5.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>../skin/frontend/<pkgname>/<themename>/js/jquery.imageCache.js</script></action>                 
    </reference>
```

If you then view page source of your home page, you'll see the two jquery libraries getting loaded up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: have included them in page.xml hope thats a good practice !! will also try your answer

Comment: Loading them in page.xml will work, but you'll be loading up those jq libs on every page then and it sounds like you only need them on the home page.